# Meaning of ""I won't let a flat tire get me down," Tom said, without despair""

Tags: phrase-meaning, jokes

I've been reading [Tom Swifties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Swifty) on [a website](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/humor/tom-swifties.html), and could not understand one of them:

> "I won't let a flat tire get me down," Tom said, **without despair.**

Where is the pun in that?

Comment: I've been wondering for a month now why your username is "CowperKettle," accompained by an icon of a _copper_ kettle, when the name "Cowper" is pronounced "kOOper." Can you enlighten me?

Comment: Oh, @P.E.Dant - [my profile](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/2127/cowperkettle?tab=profile) explains it. (0:

Comment: Great song! But "Cowper" is _not_ pronounced like "copper." Well, perhaps the connection is too subtle for me.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I was asking for an explanation of a line from Cowper's poem on this site, and someone commented that I should rename myself CowperKettle, so I did.

Comment: Ah! Now it makes sense. Good choice!

Comment: @P.E.Dant - thank you! ^_^ I've expanded the info in the profile to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Despair" sounds like "the spare." Alas

> "I won't let a *flat tire* get me down," Tom said, without "*the spare*".

The definition of *spare* at [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/spare) includes

> A spare tire

---

Note: at first I thought it was a pun on "without the air", but realised it was "without the spare."

Comment: Though that doesn't really make sense as having a spare would be more likely to be associated with a positive attitude to flats then being without one. Looks like he uses the same technique again a bit further down a bit more successfully IMO *"I haven't caught a fish all day!" Tom said, without debate.*

Comment: It's good to note that the "d" and short "th" sound *similar*, but not the same. (Well, except in certain accents...) And, slightly less related, the "f" and long "th" sounds are not identical either.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 /ð/ and /θ/ (International Phonetic Alphabet) are not "long" and "short", they are voiced and voiceless. They are exactly the same length. You can't be blamed for not knowing this; it's just another example of how the stupid orthography obfuscates the linguistic understanding of its speakers.

Comment: @EMBLEM I know they're the same length; that was just the only name I knew for them. Thank you for enlightening us all with your IPA knowledge! :-)

Comment: I wonder if it's really "without **the** spare": maybe "without **a** spare" is more grammatical. I mean, if it were not a pun but just a usual sentence. Articles always make me stop and wonder.

Comment: @CowperKettle puns don't have to be grammatically correct or even make logical sense (even though it helps). You just need to be in the right ballpark.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I fully agree, it's just that I heard "a" in this joke in my mind after Alan explained it.

Comment: @CowperKettle - Definitely *the* spare, when talking about car tyres. It's not countable: every car has one and only one spare tyre.

Comment: Definitely *the spare*, just like  *the steering wheel* and *the  trunk*, there's only one, so it illicits the use of *the*. (They are countable, but the count goes only to one.) I did not include in my answer that *de* is used to stand for *the* in many other contexts, mostly of a joking and/or slang  nature. Although it could be part of a dialect also.   Whatever, native speakers can readily interpret *despair* as *the spare*.

Comment: I guess I meant *licits* not *illicits*. If those are even verbs... :)

Answer (score 9):

I think it's a multifaceted pun.

1. "Get me down" (as in, becoming sad) vs. "despair" (also as in sadness)
2. "Flat" (as in, without emotion) compared to "without despair" (also as in the absence of emotion)
3. "Despair" compared to "the spare"
4. When you get a flat tire, your car drops down a little bit, right? Compare to "get me **down**"

This is really quite a clever compound pun, it seems to me.

Comment: Meanings or facets 1, 2, and 5 would be the most classic Tom Swifties, I believe.

Comment: Well, yeah, the meaning of despair is not irrelevant to the play on words. It could not be a pun if that were not the case.